# Visual Studio DropDownList not dropping down

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am working on a c# form in Visual Studio. I have two Combo Boxes, the first one to select country and the second to select region/state/etc

If I feed the data to a list box it seems to work fine, so i know that the data is there, but when i try to put it into combobox2 I can't get it to drop down

Any assistance would be greatly appreciates as I am really stuck

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ITS40720;Initial Catalog=VisualStudio;Integrated Security=True;");
conn.Open();
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("select SubdivisionName from dbo.Locations where CountryName = '" + comboBox1.Text + "'", conn);
SqlDataReader reader;

reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Countryname", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("SubdivisionName", typeof(string));
dt.Load(reader);

comboBox2.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
comboBox2.FormattingEnabled = true;
comboBox2.ValueMember = "Countryname";
comboBox2.DisplayMember = "SubdivisionName";
comboBox2.DataSource = dt;

conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sql query should be

```
select SubdivisionName, Countryname from ...
```

and check result of your query, perhaps it returns no data.

Do not use `Countryname` as ValueMember of combobox2, I suggest use `SubdivisionId` intead of.

```
select SubdivisionName, SubdivisionId from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your query , it does not return any value related to combobox, the query should select  **`SubdivisionName, Countryname`**

```
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("select SubdivisionName,Countryname from dbo.Locations where CountryName = '" + comboBox1.Text + "'", conn);

comboBox2.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
comboBox2.FormattingEnabled = true;
comboBox2.ValueMember = "Countryname";
comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Countryname";
comboBox2.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: The query itself was working fine, I know that because the data is displayed in a listbox with no issues. When I try to put that data in a drop-down list clicking does not make it drop down. I have removed the Column for CountryName though

Comment: does it return the related data?

Comment: it returns exaclty what I want it to return. If i add a third combobox with style "simple" it shows and is clickable [AS SEEN HERE](http://i.imgur.com/vRXK2y9.png)

Comment: Sure. [Form1.Designer.cs](https://paste.ofcode.org/36dZXxaK5qSpde6QfVtwk8G)   [Form1.cs](https://paste.ofcode.org/NhM2b8r2qAzBYwhDnvDvEX)

Comment: ops, its hard to read the entire code, if you give teamviewer. can debug and check

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting two required columns for dropdown

Your SQL Query should be

`select CountryName,SubdivisionName from dbo.Locations where CountryName='COUNTRY'`